# How to tell if Javascript can be moved to external file

Tags: javascript

How can you tell if inline javascript can be moved to an external file. Can most javascript that's located in the `<head>` of a html document be moved to external and linked to?

For SEO purposes I'm trying to help a client cleanup their javascript but I'm not totally sure it they will be able to move it to external or not.

Having in external files should increase page load speed - correct?

Comment: I can't see why all JavaScript can't be moved to an external file.

Comment: There is no hard-and-fast method. Pay attention to the order in which separate script blocks run so you don't break any dependencies, and make sure that any which access DOM elements are run after the DOM is ready.

Comment: Javascript location shouldn't affect SEO.

Comment: @Javalsu if you write content to your page via Javascript, it may not be indexed by a crawler. Maybe that's what he means by "cleaning up" - having the content hard coded in the HTML.

Comment: This makes no real sense. All JS should be external, ideally in one file linked to right at the bottom of the document. SEO might care about page speed, and speed is always good, so it's worth doing. It's a pain to retrofit though, as you don't really know what the coder did.

Comment: All that will matter is the order you load the external javascript files.

Comment: @Renan, you need to follow the ajax crawling scheme.  Either way, javascript location still wouldn't affect SEO

Comment: Having in external files should increase page load speed - correct?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know in respect to SEO, but unless you're mixing JavaScript with a server-side language like PHP (as in, creating JavaScript variables with PHP), then you should be safe to move it all to an external script.

Comment: Having in external files should increase page load speed - correct?

Comment: Assuming your external files are minified or really small, the only (noticeable) overhead you get is the HTTP request associated with it... but for practicalitys sake, I think externalizing scripts is a better idea for maintainability.

Comment: I should also add that even the HTTP request is negligible since the browser can cache your .js file, whereas it can't be cached if you just include it in a <script> tag.

Comment: Seiyria... Then that means using an http request would speed things up since the browser can cache it right?